# Integration of Jenkins and Atlassian Bamboo

Tags: android, jenkins, emulation, functional-testing, bamboo

I'm trying to get functional Android tests to run on Bamboo that require a running emulator. The problem is just that there is no such thing like the very fine [Android Emulator Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin) for Bamboo and hand-writing emulator-control in Bamboo Shell Scripts not only sounds scary, but actually is.

And since I know that "it just works" (tm) in the Jenkins world I wondered if there is any way to interleave these both CI systems with each other, like kicking off a build that is configured on the Jenkins instance in Bamboo and returning the results there for evaluation, basically as if Bamboo would control Jenkins as a "slave" instance.

Another option would be to take the open-sourced Android Emulator Plugin and try to wrap its code into a Bamboo Add-On, which would probably be a project on its own. (Remember, all I want is to continously execute some functional tests... :)

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can trigger a build on jenkins via the remote access api of jenkins. Fairly straight forward. All you need is a tool to set off a http post e.g. curl. (see here https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API)

Then you only need your bamboo and jenkins instance to agree on a shared directory of where to put the artifacts of that jenkins build afterwards.